# Has the Israeli Intelligence Service, or Army (Mossad, IDF) ever been implicated in human trafficking?

Tags: military, israel, human-rights, crime, intelligence-service

Given that the operatives of Israel are almost entirely self financed, and that Israeli crime groups often engage in drug dealing, prostitution etc, it seems feasible that they may or may not have been involved in the human labor market. Is there any evidence or court cases involving such? Preferably if people could provide info from legitimate, non-politically biased sources such as Amnesty etc.

Serious question here. I'd appreciate if you don't have an answer, or are a radical Zionist, please don't respond. Please keep this, simple, logical, and coherent.

Comment: I've been following the Israeli-Palestinian conflict for awhile, and this is something I've never heard of, even from the most militant anti-Zionists. It might be helpful if you explained *why* you're asking the question: is this a common accusation, or an accusation someone has made? Or is it something you just happen to think they'd do?

Comment: If you don't like the question, don't answer it, but it's still valid and applicable to the forum.

Comment: The question is better now, although it still sounds more like something I'd find on [Skeptics.SE] than here.  That said, is there a reason you're asking this specifically about the Israeli forces & organized crime and not their equivalents in other countries?  The self-financing?

Comment: Well, the American and British have already been documented performing this kind of thing, as have the North Koreans,etc. Hence the question, I realize that there are a lot of anti-jewish/israeli trolls, However I'm asking a serious question about state sponsored international crime.

Comment: "Given that the operatives of Israel are almost entirely self financed" - *[citation needed]*

Comment: @Cbaker510 my question is, what standard of evidence would be a sufficient answer if they aren't doing this? I've never heard of the IDF doing this, and it seems we cannot find reports of it. Is that sufficient as an answer?

Comment: Right, in terms of the IDF, I don't "know" hence the question. However, I have witnessed former IDF regulars dealing ecstasy in SEA, as well as being involved in importation to the USA. This is fairly well documented, by the American DEA, and FBI, as well as INTERPOL. It seems a short walk to dealing drugs at blue moon parties to trafficking in human beings, especially if one develops a stimulant habit.

Comment: @Cbaker510 - Yes, former intelligence agents can end up as criminals. Government pensions are pretty small compared to what crime pays, and skillsets are in demand. Probably half of USSR "power" officers ended up that way at some point. Your point being?

Comment: Writing "[if you are] are a radical Zionist, please don't respond" probably actively harms your point. As someone who knows only a little about the conflict and wants to find out the phrasing makes me switch off from the question. Surely we should also be interested in the opinions of people who consider themselves Zionists, as long as these are well-reasoned and genuine.

Comment: It is not a strange question. The region is part warzone and millitary personel in other warzones, warring factions and UN-peacekeers alike - have been known to traffick people. Mostly children for rape.

Answer (score 4):

#### Short answer

The US government says [no](http://www.state.gov/j/tip/rls/tiprpt/countries/2013/215486.htm).  (Though I guess that source doesn't count for people worried about this issue).

#### Second short answer

No, normally they just kill them.

#### Longer Answer

Firstly let's define the reasons for a kidnapping that would make it *for the purpose of human trafficking*:

- Sexual exploitation
- Forced labor
- Extraction of organs

(I took those from the opening paragraph of Wikipedia on Human Trafficking; if there are others that are commonly part of human trafficking just point it out in the comments (Different definitions yadda yadda - if it persuades me I'll add it in)).

There is no evidence that points to sexual exploitation or organ harvesting done by the Mossad at all and much less on kidnapped people.

At a stretch - a really big stretch - there is (disputable) evidence that they do force prisoners to labor (http://www.imemc.org/article/21475). However, this source doesn't really seem objective and I wasn't actually able to find proof that Israel does forced labor in its prisons at all (I'm sure they have some job program that tries to help with reintegration, which would partly explain those accusations).

IF those accusations are true there remains the question: does Mossad kidnap people?

They do; For example, various high-ranking nazi officials (Eichmann) and I'm pretty sure there was a nuclear scientist (Source is the Ostrovsky book).

About the Mossad financing: The offical budget of the Mossad is [almost 2.000.000.000 US$](http://www.haaretz.com/news/diplomacy-defense/.premium-1.597598) (For comparsion [CIA budget $14.7 billion](http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/black-budget-summary-details-us-spy-networks-successes-failures-and-objectives/2013/08/29/7e57bb78-10ab-11e3-8cdd-bcdc09410972_story.html)) - yes there have been examples where intelligence agencies have stretched their budget with let's say questionable activities (Iran-Contra comes to mind) - but to this date there have been no such allegations by credible sources (if you do find some please correct me). And keep in mind that the CIA isn't much older than Mossad so I think it's safe to say that you cannot reliably accuse Mossad (or IDF) of doing that.

Comment: "No, normally they just kill them" - do you have any example OTHER than Eichmann?

Comment: @DVK For the Mossad killing people? It honestly is a no brainer to come up with examples. Wikipedia lists enough examples - but if you want some here: Everything Kidon does, Operation Wrath of God, an assassination in Dubai some years back, the fact that Iraninan nuclear scientists seem to have an awful lot of road accidents, ...

Comment: how are any of those related to kidnapping?

Comment: @DVK I've meant that normally/most often the Mossad doesn't kidnap but kills the person in their home country. But for instances the Mossad kidnapped people? There was a try to kidnap Umaru Dikko, again Eichmann (I actually thought there were more Nazis but it doesn't seem so), in the Ostrovsky book it is IMPLIED that the nuclear scientist is kidnapped (I only skimmed the text)(or at least was firstly taken into 'custody' and then given the 'offer' to work with Israel) and one could argue that Palestine is almost another state so any person taken from there is kidnapped. But again, kidnapping

Comment: is rather rare - probably because it isn't needed (I think e.g. the Iranian nuclear scientiest can't teach the Israelis anything but 'disposing' of them does set back Iran's capacity)

Comment: Why don't you guys just censor this, I'll just ask on a site that isn't politically biased/founded by a former IDF soldier. Thanks.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Iran-Contra was NOT used to finance CIA budget, but that of **Contras** (hence the name)

Comment: @DVK ok I think there's an issue with the "stretched their budget". 1. CIA wants to finance contras (So money flows from the CIA budget to them). 2. CIA can't ask for money for that purpose (Boland Amendment) 3. CIA gets money by selling arms 4. That money isn't known to Congress and can thus be used to help the Contras.   My wording maybe implied that the money stayed at the CIA but they 'invested' it.

Comment: @user45891 - the point is, they didn't do it to finance themselves - they had enough money. They did it to finance someone else that they weren't allowed to finance for political (non-financial) reasons.

Comment: @user45891 - minor technical note: while I'm not an expert but AFAIK, Palestinian territories aren't Mossad bailywick. That'd be SHABAK or specops

Comment: I'm with DVK here. A lot of these things are unrelated to OP's question. This answer should be trimmed down, then it's a good one.

Comment: @Cbaker510 - I don't understand people who ask questions, then refuse to accept the answer because of perceived issues with the people doing the answering.  You asked a relatively straight-forward question.  The *easy* answer is "There's no indication of anything like that". The more involved answer is "Here's a list of reasons why it wouldn't happen".  Now, it's up to you to either accept that **there is no information publicly available to be able to say "yes"** or to stick your head in the sand and **keep your preconceived notions**.  If the latter, why bother asking in the first place?

Comment: US is not "non-politically biased sources"

Answer (score 2):

Trying not to be blinded by the question's bias, it might be interesting to restate it:

> Given that crime groups in [Country X] often engage in drug dealing,
>   prostitution, etc, it seems feasible that military or intelligence
>   personal in [Country X] may <strike>or may not</strike> have been involved in
>   the human labor market. Is there any evidence, or court cases
>   involving such?

I'm going to assume that the use of "may or may not" was an error, since leaving it in place makes the sentence pointless. (e.g. "I may or may not be naked right now." Other than the possible smirk it elicits, the sentence has no value.)

Let's simplify it even more so we can analyze it:

> Given X is true, it seems feasible that Y would be true. Is there any
>   evidence that Y is true?

In order for the question to be interesting, the reader should agree with X, and also agree that the leap to Y is "feasible". I think that's where this question breaks down. The leap is too great to convince the reader that "Since crime groups in Iceland engage in drug dealing and prostitution, then it's likely that military or intelligence personal in Iceland are involved in the human labor market."

I selected Iceland only because it has one of the lowest crime rates in the world, highlighting the absurdity of the statement. Any country you substitute should have the same problem. Note the statement is flawed even if you substitute a country that does have military or intelligence personal involved in the human labor market!

Finally, the actual question by itself (as stated in the title) is valid, but unfortunately the question is spoiled by the explanation behind it. That being said, even the question by itself has very little value, making it a poor choice of question on this site. Kind of like:

> Is there any evidence that President Obama was born on Mars, and if
>   yes, then how can he be an American Citizen?

As Bobson pointed out in his comment and nearly one word answer, you must be willing to accept the answer of "No", which is pretty darned boring.